# Audio doesn't work for PlayOneShot but works for Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get audio working (a short clip) each time I click the mouse button. It works if I call Play directly. But I want to have the option to pass in audioclip thus using PlayOneShot but there is no audio. Its not a volume issue as I have tried to pass in the argument for volume with no difference. The audio clip has been added to the inspector.

Please advice. Thank you.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip impactSound;

    void Start () {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            //audioSource.Play(); // This works
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(impactSound, 0.8f); // not working
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no audio because you did NOT assign your audio file to the `impactSound` slot. Select `impactSound` and drag your audio to it. It should play audio after this.

You won't get any exception if the audio is not assigned in the Editor.The audio will simply not play. If you've already done this and audio is not playing, double click on that audio to make sure that it actually plays outside Unity.

Comment: I had added it to audio source but not impactSound. Nice spot. Thanks.

Comment: That happens sometimes. Wish Unity would show an error message to make it easier to spot.